# find the least positive integer x satisfying both 3x≡11 (mod 17) and 5x≡9 (mod 23)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Q.find the least positive integer x satisfying both 3x≡11 (mod 17) and 5x≡9 (mod 23)

How to solve problems like this? Using CRT theorem?

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem is for solving simultaneous congruences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various methods. The following uses your problem to illustrate one approach.

Here with coprime moduli and solvable congruences (moduli are prime, so everything has a multiplicative inverse) CRT guarantees one solution modulo $17\times 23=(20-3)(20+3)=400-9=391$.

It is easiest, I think, to reduce to a standard form, noting that $3\times 6=18\equiv 1 \bmod 17$ and $5\times 14=70 \equiv 1\bmod 23$ so multiply the first by $6$ and the second by $14$ obtaining $$x\equiv 66\equiv 15\equiv-2\bmod 17$$ (don't be afraid of introducing negative numbers into the computations if it keeps the arithmetic easy) and $$x\equiv 126\equiv 11\bmod 23$$

These can be combined as $$x=17a-2=23b+11$$Now we echo the Euclidean algorithm, adding extra variables, but taking care to reduce the coefficients. First set $c=a-b$ which gives $$17c=6b+13$$Then $d=b-2c$ so that $$5c=6d+13$$ and with $e=c-d$ we have $$5e=d+13$$

Here we have $d=2, e=3$ then $c=5, b=12,a=17$

Answer (score 0):

Given
\begin{align}
&x\equiv\frac{11}3\pmod{17}&
&x\equiv\frac 95\pmod{23}
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
&\frac{11}{3\cdot\color{orange}{23}}\equiv\color{red}{11}\pmod{\color{green}{17}}&
&\frac{9}{5\cdot\color{green}{17}}\equiv\color{blue}{2}\pmod{\color{orange}{23}}
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
x\equiv\color{red}{11}\cdot\color{orange}{23}+\color{blue}{2}\cdot \color{green}{17}=287\pmod{\color{green}{17}\cdot\color{orange}{23}}
\end{align}
is the smallest solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am confused of the using 11/3*23 and 9/5*17 what does it means?

Comment: You can divide by integers coprime to the modulus.